# Pointers in C: Data type or operation

Tags: c, pointers

Would we call the pointers in C a data type (of type void*) or just an operation done on an unsigned integer which makes its value get interpreted as a virtual memory address ? If it is a data type, which hardware and software factors impact its range ?

Comment: pointers do have a type

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mixing two things together - Indirection operator and pointer variables.

**Indirection operator (*)** - The indirection operator is a unary operator that can be used to obtain the value stored at the memory location referenced by a pointer variable.

**pointer variables** - In C pointers are variables of specific type (e.g. int,char, void) that store addresses and can be null.

The size of pointers depends upon different factors. You can go to below link. They have explained it well.

[What is the size of a pointer? What exactly does it depend on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23185096/what-is-the-size-of-a-pointer-what-exactly-does-it-depend-on)

Answer (score 1):

C thinks your whole computer is one massive array of bytes. Obviously this isn't very useful, but then C layers on top of this massive array of bytes the concept of types and sizes of those types.

- Creating a block of memory inside your computer.
- "Pointing" the name `ptr` at the beginning of that block().

This indirectly means it needs a type specifier which will be same as the data type it is pointing to.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are data types. Like `void *`.

`intptr_t` integers can store any pointers except function pointers. So you can think of such pointers to data objects as special integers. (But remember integer and pointer are different types.)

Your compiler generates code for your target environment. E.g. if you compile with the option `-m32` then pointer size is probably 32 bits. It can be run on 32-bit architecture where the CPU register can store 32-bit memory address. Although 64-bit architecture may still support 32-bit application, you can use the option `-m64` for compilation to benefit from bigger pointers (probably 64 bits).

Answer (score 1):

You're asking about a lot of ideas.  I'm going to try and cite the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) as much as possible to give the official idea, then break it down into something digestible.

---

**Would we call the pointers in C a data type (of type void *) or just an operation done on an unsigned integer which makes its value get interpreted as a virtual memory address?**

From the C standard:

> **6.2.5 Types**
>
> 20. A *pointer type* may be derived from a function type, an object type, or an incomplete type, called the *referenced type*. A pointer type describes an object whose value provides a reference to an entity of the referenced type. A pointer type derived from the referenced type *T* is sometimes called ‘‘pointer to *T*’’. The construction of a pointer type from a referenced type is called ‘‘pointer type derivation’’.
>
> **6.3.2.3 Pointers**
>
> 5. An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.
> 6. Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer type.

A pointer isn't a data type (at least in the traditional sense of the phrase) or an integer - it's a C programmer's way of denoting the location of a certain object. While we tend to think of that as being a number - i.e., `0xf000b3a8` - there's no reason it *has* to be a number. It just has to mark the location of a particular object.  Furthermore, the type of the object it points to dictates its own *pointer type*. So a pointer with type of "`float *`" is equivalent to "pointer to `float`". It is *not* a `float` type - it's a pointer type.

For a concrete example of this, think about how you organize your bedroom - perhaps you have a bed, a desk, a set of drawers, a closet, and a bedside table. Before you go to bed, you pull out a sticky note and write "Remember headphones on desk".  You then put that sticky note on your backpack.  That sticky note is a *pointer* to your headphones! It represents a reminder to you of where those headphones are located - your desk, *not* a number.

The reason we tend to think of pointers as integers is from sections 6.3.2.3.5 and 6.3.2.3.6.  Computers - as they're currently designed - don't understand the concept of "a desk" or "a closet".  They only understand numbers - so we organize them accordingly.  As a result, the C standard dictates that integers must be able to be converted into pointers, and vice-versa.

---

**If it is a data type, which hardware and software factors impact its range?**

Again, a pointer isn't really a data type - it denotes the location of a certain object (that in turn has a certain type that dictates the pointer's type).  So we can't really talk about the *range* of a pointer, per se. What we *can* talk about is the range of possible memory addresses (and thus the range of possible locations that a pointer could point to!).

Back in the day, when dinosaurs roamed the earth and Nixon was in office (I'm a young'un, what can I say), Intel came out with the Intel 8008 microprocessor<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8008)</sup>.  This puppy was the world's first **8-bit** CPU - that is, it could perform mathematical operations on 8-bit values. Assuming 2's complement notation, this allows unsigned values of 0 to 2<sup>8</sup>-1 (0 to 255) and signed values of -2<sup>7</sup> to 2<sup>7</sup>-1 (-128 to 127). Furthermore, it had an external 14-bit address bus that could address up to 16KB of memory.  This equates to 2<sup>14</sup> (16384) memory locations, each containing 8 bits.  The full range is thus from byte 0 to byte 16383.

Fast-forward to today.  Most modern desktop and laptop PCs run on 64-bit processors.  These support (theoretically) 2<sup>64</sup> bytes of memory - a whopping 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 locations.  This equates to approximately 16 exabytes - where one exabyte is 1,000,000 terabytes. ([It's speculated that Google stores approximately this much data in their datacenters](http://what-if.xkcd.com/63/)).  Currently, however, most architectures only use the lower 48-bits<sup>[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Architectural_features)</sup>.

These represent the total number of **physical** locations that a pointer in C could theoretically point to.  In reality, because of how virtual memory works, the range that you as a programmer will see is far more limited.  That's a story for another day, however.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is a variable whose value is the address of another variable. Generally speaking, a pointer in C can point to any address within the virtual memory, and NULL.

Comment: Pointers may only point to objects that exist (or one past the end of those objects), or null.  Trying to point anywhere else causes undefined behaviour in Standard C.  (Some implementations may offer it as an extension)

Answer (score -2):

A pointer is generally a variable whose value is the address of another variable, e.g. *direct address of the memory location*. Like any variable or constant, you must declare a pointer before you can use it to store any variable address.

The actual data type of the value of all pointers, whether integer, float, character, or otherwise, is the same, a long hexadecimal number that represents a memory address.

e.g: `int *ip;    /* pointer to an integer */`

The run-time representation of a pointer value is typically a **raw memory** address (perhaps augmented by an offset-within-word field), but since a pointer's type includes the type of the thing pointed to, expressions including pointers **can be type-checked at compile time**. Pointer arithmetic is automatically scaled by the size of the pointed-to data type.

AS for void pointers (`void *`) point to objects of unspecified type, and can therefore be used as "generic" data pointers. Since the size and type of the pointed-to object is not known, void pointers cannot be dereferenced, nor is pointer arithmetic on them allowed, although they can easily be (and in many contexts implicitly are) converted to and from any other object pointer type.

[See wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29#Pointers)

Comment: The actual data type of a pointer is... a pointer of that type.  It's not a number (much less a hexadecimal number, whatever that's supposed to mean)

Comment: This "*The actual data type of the value of all pointers [...] is the same*" in general is wrong, as there might be systems were pointers to different types of objects have different implementations, for example different sizes.